# Ubuntu 12.10 low video quality

Tags: drivers, hd-video

I've been using Ubuntu since two months and one thing that worry me is that the video quality while playing HD videos is not that good as it is in windows. So I want to ask you if you know some way to increase the quality of video. Here is the output from

```
sudo lshw -C display

*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GF119 [GeForce GT 610]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

Also I'm using VLC player to play videos and for video output rendering I'm using OpenGL GLX video output (I tried and other video output rendering that vlc provides but found that was the best of them yet not so good...).

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: VLC considered as the best Video Player (Open Source of course) but the settings are complicated. So many settings for different video formats - files ..etc. I think that guys in VLC have made a great job with default settings so I suggest to not search for a guide of improvement. At the other side , check your Nvidia-Settings panel and uncheck the "Sync to Vblank" , sometimes help. Also you can read the [VideoLan Wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Main_Page) , it might help you.

Comment: I also face this same problem. In Windows the same media file looks very clear and high quality.